# Docker: access denied on pulic github repo

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, ghcr

I am trying to run "docker-compose up" on the docker-compose.yml below (the environment variable are defined in a .env file).

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  ib-gateway:
    image: ghcr.io/unusualalpha/ib-gateway:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      TWS_USERID: ${TWS_USERID}
      TWS_PASSWORD: ${TWS_PASSWORD}
      TRADING_MODE: ${TRADING_MODE:-live}
      VNC_SERVER_PASSWORD: ${VNC_SERVER_PASSWORD:-}
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4001:4001"
      - "127.0.0.1:4002:4002"
      - "127.0.0.1:5900:5900"
```

(see github repo [here](https://github.com/UnusualAlpha/ib-gateway-docker) for more info).

And I am getting the following error:

```
> PS C:\Users\rapha\Documents\Github\ib-gateway-docker> docker-compose up
> Running 0/1
> ib-gateway Error                                                                                                0.5s
> Error response from daemon: Head "https://ghcr.io/v2/unusualalpha/ib-gateway/manifests/latest": denied: denied
```

The url contains the following message:

> {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required"}]}

What puzzles me is the following:

1. If I follow the exact same procedure on my second machine, it works like a charm
2. It is a public repo, so I should not need to login anyway

Any idea where this error might be coming from?

Comment: Do you have, by any chance, stored your github-credentials on the 2nd machine?

Comment: No. The second machine is actually brand new, just installed the bear minimum to code like an IDE, Docker Destop and a few other things.